# Converting a DataRow to a single object - type constraints

Tags: c#, oop, generics, type-constraints

I have the following implementation that works for converting rows in a `DataTable` to a `List<T>`. The `IDataItem` interface just contains the `SetData` method that takes in a single `DataRow` object.

```
public class GroupedData<T> : List<T> where T : IDataItem, new()
    {
        public GroupedData(DataTable table)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
                var newItem = new T();
                newItem.SetData(row);
                Add(newItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

These are the properties in the class I am trying to assign values to:

```
  public class Details
  {
    public List<AuditData> AuditEntries { get; set; }

    public AuditMethodSummaryData AuditMethodSummaryData { get; set; }
  }
```

With the GroupedData class, I can execute the following to populate AuditEntries:

```
var returnData = new Details();
returnData.AuditEntries = new GroupedData<AuditData>(dataSet.Tables[TableNames.AuditDetails]);
```

For the second property, AuditMethodSummaryData. I need to assign a single object instead of a List. I can't figure out how to create another class that can perform the function.

Note - I still need to pass in a DataTable. However, the data table will only ever contain a single row (due to the way the system works).

The only solution I've came up with is below. I just want to see if there is a better solution:

```
public class SingleData
  {
    public static T GetItem<T>(DataTable table) where T : IDataItem, new()
    {
      if (table.Rows.Count >= 1)
      {
        DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
        var newItem = new T();
        newItem.SetData(row);
      }
    }
  }
```

What I don't like is that i've moved the constraint from the class to the method. Is there a way I can keep it on the class? Avoiding the static method.

Comment: What's the problem with making a method generic instead of the class? I can only see benefits, really...

Comment: @Luaan That is a fair point. It is also what I stuck with on the production code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for the single item you don't need generics at all:

```
public class SingleItem : IDataItem
{
  public SingleItem(DataTable table)
  {
    if (table.Rows.Count >= 1)
    {
      var row = table.Rows[0];
      SetData(row);
    }
    else
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("No rows.", "table");
    }
  }

  public abstract void SetData(DataRow row);
}

public AuditMethodSummaryData : SingleItem
{
  public AuditMethodSummaryData(DataTable table) : base(table)
  {}
  public override void SetData(DataRow row) { /*...*/ }
}
```

This still doesn't solve case when you need to return `null` for zero rows. In that case you have to use factory pattern - which can be implemented in various ways - static method is the easy and I think decent approach for your case; if you don't want to have static method you have to create factory class instead like:

```
public class DataItemFactory<T> where T : IDataItem, new()
{
  private readonly DataTable m_Table;

  public DataItemFactory(DataTable table)
  {
    m_Table = table;
  }

  public T Create()
  {
    T result = default(T);
    if (m_Table.Rows.Count > 1)
    {
      result = new T();
      result.SetData(m_Table.Rows[0]);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

With usage like:

```
returnData.AuditMethodSummaryData =
  new DataItemFactory<AuditMethodSummaryData>(table).Create();
```